# unable to add google play services library in project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed google play services from sdk manager in eclipse, however, when I go to project properties -> android tab there is no library to add all I've got is ..\appcompat_v7

Can you please help

Comment: it's time to migrate to Android Studio:) However Play Services now has form of gradle plugin, so you need to find a way to apply this plugin to your project

Comment: that's true @ViktorYakunin untill I got a new machine I won't be able to install android studio since I've got a very low performance on my machine

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk this should help. You need to add the lib manually it is located in sdk/extras/google/google_play_services

Comment: @ViktorYakunin thank you so much. I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check that you imported the library onto the same physical drive as your project? This is a common mistake and as far as I know official documentation doesn't mention it.